# How do I install the wimtools package on Debian Jessie?

Tags: debian, apt, raspbian

I've installed a fresh install of Raspbian Jessie and run the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then trying to install `wimtools` I get this error.

```
$ sudo apt-get install wimtools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package wimtools
```

I want `wimtools` because I want to be able to run `mkwinpeimg` once installed.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Raspbian is a close derivative of Debian, so most of the informations at Debian usually also applies for Raspbian as long as they are not hardware/boot/install related.

The *wimtools* package [appeared in Debian *unstable*](https://tracker.debian.org/news/746451/accepted-wimlib-183-1-source-amd64-all-into-unstable-unstable/) in 2016 after [*jessie* was released](https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/) in 2015. It is thus not available in *jessie*. Since except for backports and some exceptions a package always appears in *unstable*, transitions to the *testing* state and becomes *stable*  when the *testing* codename (which was *stretch* in 2016) transitions to the *stable* status, it became "officially" available when *stretch* was released in 2017.

You should then either:

- Upgrade *jessie* to *stretch*, where [wimtools](https://packages.debian.org/source/stable/wimlib) is [available](https://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/w/wimlib/) (don't attempt to install for *jessie* packages intended for *stretch* or *buster*). This raspbian blog has a short explanation on the upgrade process: https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspbian-stretch/. Raspbian recommends a reinstallation rather than an upgrade so I won't detail it.
- reinstall to *stretch* or *buster*. It appears Raspbian didn't wait Debian to release [buster](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/release_notes.txt) on 2019-06-20 and is now offering *buster* [installation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) rather than *stretch* (which can still be found [here](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/images/raspbian-2019-04-09/)).
- Backport from sources the stable package to *jessie*. Sometimes this requires *also* backporting packages on which this set of packages depends upon to run or to build.
  Here's a Debian link showing how to do such backports: https://wiki.debian.org/SimpleBackportCreation

If you had no compelling reason to install *jessie* rather than one of the two newer available versions you should reinstall with latest supported release from Rasbian, which now appears to be *buster* having superseded *stretch* since a few days (most probably for proper support for RPi 4).